# How to design a database for food delivery application like swiggy and zomato?

Tags: database-design

Should I create a separate table for each new users providing the information of the restaurant they own and the menu they provide?

Should I create a separate table for each user to store the data of orders they place?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will be a very basic design which you can think of. Have a table named hotels -  a list of all hotels with name,  address,  type of food, along with a primary key (unique identifier).

Menus - have the above table's unique identifier and add menus. So, when you need to reference the menu,  you can use that key, and also have a PK for this.

Users - name, info and address with a unique identifier for each user (userid)(preferably JSON).

Orders - order number(PK) , userid, hotel (primary key), items (from menu), menu id

Hope this helps.

Comment: if a hotel has 100 menus then the same primary key of hotel should be added in menu table 100 times .is there any solution to solve this redundancy?

Comment: the menu will be same across the whole hotel.. i dont see a reason that you cannot have multiple menus at the same hotel.. i know some hotels will have different menus for different age groups - but then it has to be added in a different manner. plus the data entry should be done by the program like admin console for the website... which will handle all this redundancy

Comment: If this answer is useful, please consider to tick it as answer. thanks

Comment: sorry i meant 100 items in the menu

Comment: aah,, got it ... so in that case you have to create a another table for items which will have a link up with menu id .. as the items in a menu can change every now and then ..and that table will have all the link like menuid, hotelid, etc

Comment: so should i create new menu table for each new hotel that is getting registered or should i have a single table and add each hotels menu items with its Hotelid..